# set input max length with php

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to set a max value to my inputs. I can do it with html but anyone can easily overwrite that in any browser's inspect menu. So I want to use php to set it. I don't really know where I should put it and if this is the right way or not.

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "reg");
mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Escape user inputs for security
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['name']);
$job = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['job']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['email']);
$phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['phone']);
$phone2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['phone2']);
$address = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['address']);
$description = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['description']);
$visibility = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['visibility']);

// attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO cards (name, job, email, phone, phone2, address, description, visibility) VALUES ('$name', '$job', '$email', '$phone', '$phone2', '$address', '$description', '$visibility')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    header("Location: addbusiness.php?message=1");
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

if(strlen($name) > 10)
{
echo "Max value is 10";
}

// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

```
<label>Name</label>
<input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" type="text" required="required">
```

Comment: You should also learn to use prepared statements instead of substituting variables. Escaping is not an adequate solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the `strlen()` check *before* you perform the insert, and not insert anything if the check fails.

```
if(strlen($name) > 10)
{
    echo "Max value is 10";
    exit();
}
// attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO cards (name, job, email, phone, phone2, address, description, visibility) VALUES ('$name', '$job', '$email', '$phone', '$phone2', '$address', '$description', '$visibility')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    header("Location: addbusiness.php?message=1");
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
```

Comment: I get this error message if I use your code: ```Notice: Undefined index: visibility in C:\xampp\htdocs\vallalkozok-v2\insert.php on line 18```

Comment: That has nothing to do with my code. It means there was no `visibility` parameter in the form that was submitted.

Comment: The line that uses `$_REQUEST['visibility']` is before my code, it can't have any effect on it.

Comment: But without your code I don't get any errors. visibility isn't take a part of the form because it automatically gives a 0 value in the database.

Comment: You must have changed something when you added my code, I can't explain it any other way. `$_REQUEST['visibility']` will be set when there's a `visibility` parameter sent from the form or in the URL query string.

Comment: Well I just deleted the ```$_REQUEST['visibility']``` line and everyting is working cool.  Thanks for your answers, I'll also take a look at prepared statements.